# Insertion sort doesn't work

Tags: python, sorting, insertion-sort

I wrote this insertion sort, but for some reason it doesn't return anything, and I can't figure out why. Could someone take a look at this?

```
def insertionSort(lis):
    for i in range (1, len(lis)):
        j = i - 1
        value = lis[i]
        while j >= 0:
            if value < lis[j]: #have to be value because the number has to remain the same
                lis[j+1] = lis[j]
                j-= 1
            else:
                lis[j+1] = value
    return lis
```

Comment: Is that the actual indentation you're using?

Comment: Can you fix your indentation to look exactly the same as it does in your code? This code would not run.

Comment: sorry no its not, just fixed the indentation

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't return anything"?  Empty list, never returns, returns with value None, etc?

Comment: Infinite while loop. If your `if` clause doesn't trigger, `j` remains the same.

Comment: wikipedia gives a very good explanation and easy to follow  pseudocode for insertion sort, might pay to check it out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Answer (score 3):

You have an infinite loop.
In this code:

```
while j >= 0:
    if value < lis[j]: #have to be value because the number has to remain the same
        lis[j+1] = lis[j]
        j-= 1
    else:
        lis[j+1] = value
```

as soon as you reach a point where `value < lis[j]` is false, `j` is not decremented and your `while` loop will never exit.

I can write a correct insertion sort for you if you want, but I think that would defeat the point of you trying to do it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at this sample code ,It maybe helpful for you

```
def insertionSort(alist):

   for index in range(1,len(alist)):

     currentvalue = alist[index]

     position = index

  while position>0 and alist[position-1]>currentvalue:

       alist[position]=alist[position-1]

       position = position-1

  alist[position]=currentvalue


 alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]

 insertionSort(alist)

 print(alist)
```